# Is there no alternative to: "si simplement que tu te demanderas d’abord : n’aurait-il pas compris"?

Tags: subjonctif, conditionnel, concordance-des-temps

I believe this question arose from a misunderstanding of the text I quote.  I only leave it because it has been answered and the mistake was instructive to myself.  I doubt however reading this will be worthwhile to others.

---

This question is on the highlighted sentence in this passage from chapter 7 of La porte étroite by André Gide.

> – Écoute, Alissa, m’écriai-je tout d’un coup : j’ai douze jours libres devant moi. Je n’en resterai pas un de plus qu’il ne te plaira. Convenons d’un signe qui voudra dire : c’est demain qu’il faut quitter Fongueusemare. Le lendemain, sans récriminations, sans plaintes, je partirai. Consens-tu ?
>        
>   N’ayant point préparé mes phrases, je parlais plus aisément. Elle réfléchit un moment, puis :
>        
>   – Le soir où, descendant pour dîner, je ne porterai pas à mon cou la croix d’améthyste que tu aimes… comprendras-tu ?
>        
>   – Que ce sera mon dernier soir.
>        
>   – Mais sauras-tu partir, reprit-elle, sans larmes, sans soupirs…
>        
>   – Sans adieux. Je te quitterai ce dernier soir comme je l’aurais fait la veille, si simplement que tu te **demanderas** d’abord : n’**aurait**-il pas **compris** ? mais quand tu me chercheras, le lendemain matin, simplement je ne serai plus là.
>        
>   – Le lendemain je ne te chercherai plus.

**QUESTION**

Am I right in thinking that *demanderas* and *n’aurait-il pas compris* as stand above are the only way to express the thought there being expressed and that there is neither a more formal nor more colloquial alternative to it?

If there is an alternative in either direction, please tell me what it is.

**BACKGROUND**

So often do I hear that what I find in some book is "literary" and would in conversation become something else--so often that I am constantly on the look out for such a possibility.

For the clause in question above, I seem to have determined that it is the only way anyone could have put it, whether in literature or conversation, as follows.

If we were at the actual moment of Alissa's wondering, the clause would run:

> si simplement que tu te demandes d'abord : <strike>n'ait-il</strike>n'a-t-il pas compris ?

But we are not there yet.  The moment still lies in the future; so everything has to go into a future tense.  So, as the book has it:

> si simplement que tu te demanderas d’abord : n’aurait-il pas compris ?

Comment: I get that her wondering is predicted for the future, & therefore "demanderas" is the correct form for that, but it seems that she will be asking herself about a past event (whether he did or didn't really understand the whole sign/cross thing), so couldn't the question that he predicts she will ask (especially since it's presented as a quotation) be either in the passé composé ("n'a-t-il pas compris") or the past/plu perfect (n'avait-il pas compris")? (What if instead of presenting it as a quote it had been connected with "si" ("tu te demanderas d’abord s'il aurait/avais/a bien compris?)

Comment: @PapaPoule. From what I understand, Alissa's wondering is measured against the present (the time of the utterance of the whole conversation above quoted). Thus, Alissa's wondering is a *future* to that present. Next, the content of what Alissa wonders (viz. *n’aurait-il pas compris*) is measured against that future, to which it is a *past* (as you say). In sum, *n’aurait-il pas compris* is a *past* of a *future* of the present. I believe it is this compound relation that *aurait compris* expresses.

Comment: The more I read your questions about La porte étroite, the less I feel like reading that book :-)

Comment: @Frank. I'm probably trashing it. At this rate, I'll give away the ending too.

Comment: Nah - it's just all those weird tenses, subjunctive and all :-)

Comment: @PapaPoule. I believe you were totally right, and that's why my question didn't make sense. Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, I don't see a context where _si simplement que tu te demandes d'abord : n'a-t-il pas compris ?_ could be used. It is grammatically correct on its own, but it sounds _bancal_ in any interpolation of Gide's text I could think about.

Comment: @Frank. I was referring to my trying to see Alissa's thought as a *que*-clause (which was wrong). PP (correctly and as you yourself did) sees it as directly quoted. But since it is a direct quote, we must also accept that *n’aurait-il pas* is exactly what Jerome attributes to Alissa as the very form of *her* thought.

Comment: Yes, correct - it is the form of _her_ thought - sorry I didn't make that explicit, I guess it was kind of "obvious" to me (I didn't even think about it!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like this is a happy medium between more formal and more colloquial (although there are probably ways to say that in slang, but I'm not sure your question is about that). I wouldn't venture in "*n'eusse-t'il pas compris*" territory - maybe there is a subjunctive possibility (!) but I don't want to go there. One could say:

> si simplement que tu te demanderas d’abord: n’a-t-il pas compris?

In which there is less uncertainty.

One thing though:

> si simplement que tu te demandes d'abord : n'ait-il pas compris ?

Doesn't work. It would have to be, maybe (but the agreement of the tenses feels wrong):

> si simplement que tu te demandes d'abord : *n'avait-il* pas compris ?

Comment: *s'demander* does not require a subjunctive in the *que*-context? Like doubting, fearing, hoping etc.?

Comment: _s'demander_? you mean _se demander_? but there are those ":" that block the usual _que_ construction, and I can't see how to introduce a _que_ here.

Comment: That *s'demander* will tell you that I have no opportunity to *speak* French, only to read. Someone to whom it is speech would never make that sort of mistake. / I totally get what you mean by the colon. Right, Alissa would not say or think *ait-il* as if--she were describing herself. I'll fix it.

Comment: But why not just *n'a-t-il pas compris* meaning *did he not understand* (or *has he not understand*)?

Comment: If, however, the colon blocks an indirect reporting (*que*) context, then it would have the same blocking power in Gide's original. In which case, *n’aurait-il pas compris* is simply Alissa's asking that question in a tone of uncertainty? In which case, this whole question simply does not arise!

Comment: Ah - _n'a-t-il pas compris_ doesn't work, because we are talking about a future event. The original is about a past with respect to a future event, hence _n'aurait-il pas_.

Comment: But your point about the colon. Didn't that mean that the colon worked just as quotation marks do in English. A *direct* reporting of what Alissa will end up thinking? That would be *a-t-il*. No?

Comment: I think there is combination of uncertainty, Jérôme relating how Alissa would ask herself that question, and it is in the future, or a conditional future, at least...

Comment: Yes, I think _a-t-il_ would work, indeed, so _n'aurait-il_ introduces uncertainty.